# Interesting String casting

Tags: ruby, string, casting

How do I make the following string cast:

```
"ln(5*x)" -> "Math.log(5*x)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"ln(5*x)".sub('ln','Math.log') #=> "Math.log(5*x)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"math.log(#{"ln(5*x)"[/ln\((.*)\)/,1]})"
```

Comment: Ok, now, is there any gem or library to generalize the solution, transforming all the math-like strings into their Ruby expression representation (with all the Math affixes)?

Comment: You'd better search on github.com

Comment: They're just strings: treat them like strings. It's of no consequence that they look like math functions.